# Mysql hosted in Amazon aws is sometimes very slow

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

We have a database, and tables contains more than 2 million records. Database is hosted in Amazon aws server.

Sometimes the "select" query execution time is very very slow. What could be the reason behind this slow execution?

One of my query was this :

```
select UserDID, count(*) from exportusers
group by UserDID 
having count(*) > 1;
```

The query say "`executing query...`" and it never ends. I forcefully exit from the query browser.

Here is my Explain on select statement

```
mysql> Explain select count(*) from exportusers where status != 'active' and PREndDate < now() - interval 3 month and DTModified < now() - interval 3 month;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                                         | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | exportusers | range | index_jobs_on_DTModified,index_jobs_on_PREndDate,index_jobs_on_Status | index_jobs_on_DTModified | 5       | NULL | 2377287 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.30 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `UserDID`? http://rakeroutes.com/blog/increase-rails-performance-with-database-indexes/

Comment: @Simon, Yes I do have index on UserDID.

Comment: what does `explain` says for your selectstatement

Comment: @bish , what is "explain" for selectstatement? I don't get any error message or connection time out, the query say "executing query..."  and it never ends. I forcefully exit the query browser.

Comment: @joe Explain gives you information about the executed query, showing which keys and indexes etc. are used. It helps to improve statements. But when you say you have to force the query browser to shutdown I doubt it will help, never the less here is the link to MYSQL-Explain doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Looks like you could improve the statement with an index over several cols as only the index of `index_jobs_on_DTModified` is used but `EndDate` and `Status` are not. I would give a try on an index above all three cols. But further more I would'nt have an idea - maybe its amazon aws itselfs (don't know if their configurations of keybuffer, cache etc. fits well for you [I'm not a database administrator]).

Answer (score 1):

There could be a lot of reasons for a slow query on a larger table. A few:

- There is no index that can be used to speed up the query.
- The database does not have the portions of the index needed to process a request already loaded into memory.
- The requested action is competing with other queries or updates for database processing. In particular, queries and updates don't always get along well.
- You could be running your database on a micro instance which offers "bursty" performance and can at times balk at "overperforming" given its price point.
- You could be running your database on an instance that you are also using to provide web services, cron jobs, software development, email or other processing efforts.

NOTE: Some of these items may also be influenced by the database engine in use.

Comment: it was useful to analyse database and table structure. I would check these steps on my table.  Thank you. :)